# calculate standard deviation of datetime rows for specefic column and save to new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, typeerror

I have a dataframe of 277 columns and 4000+ rows in the format

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'TCTN':list('101','102','103','104')
         '0':[855days,626days,866days],
         '1':[946days,485days,182days],
         '2':[1242days,1985days,0days],
         '3':[345days,1864days,361days],
})
```

I need to find the standard deviation of individual rows and save them to a new column ['STD']
This is what i tried:

```
df3['STDDEV']=df3.apply(np.std(axis=1))
```

but i got the error:

```
TypeError: _std_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

is this because i need to convert the datatype before applying the function?
I am quite new to working with data in python, thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If working with timedeltas is better use [`DataFrame.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) with omit first column if necessary, also add `ddof=0` if need same behaviour like `np.std`, because default pandas `ddof=1`:

```
df3['STDDEV'] = df3.iloc[:, 1:].std(axis=1, ddof=0)
print (df3)
  TCTN        0        1         2         3                   STDDEV
0  101 855 days 946 days 1242 days  345 days 323 days 05:21:59.628482
1  102 626 days 485 days 1985 days 1864 days 687 days 15:28:38.826254
2  103 866 days 182 days    0 days  361 days 322 days 21:48:52.946864
```

If first column is index:

```
df3['STDDEV'] = df3.std(axis=1, ddof=0)
print (df3)
            1         2         3                   STDDEV
TCTN                                                      
101  946 days 1242 days  345 days 373 days 04:31:14.711017
102  485 days 1985 days 1864 days 680 days 09:10:40.121445
103  182 days    0 days  361 days 147 days 09:06:14.040307
```

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami - if first column `TCNN` is index then yes.